# Sequence contains more than one element - while it should contain more than one

Tags: c#, linq

I know the topic of "Sequence contains more than one element" was covered here before but I couldn't find anything that would apply to my case.
Here's the code:

```
var mailTo = db.DRAFT_DLs
    .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == argMailTo)
    .Select(dd => new MailAddress(dd.EMAIL))
    .ToList();

string mailCc = db.DRAFT_DLs
    .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == "ALL")
    .Select(dd => dd.EMAIL)
    .SingleOrDefault() ?? "";

// ...

mailTo.ForEach(rcpt => mail.To.Add(rcpt));
mail.CC.Add(mailCc);
```

Complete error message:

```
Message :System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at IncidentEmailEngine.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Dane\VS\IncidentEmailEngine\IncidentEmailEngine\Program.cs:line 94<br/>
StackTrace :   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at IncidentEmailEngine.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Dane\VS\IncidentEmailEngine\IncidentEmailEngine\Program.cs:line 94
```

And mentioned exception is thrown on the first line. The problem is that it's a list and therefore it should and contains more than one element. 

Thanks for your input on that.

Resolution:
Error was in line 95, as the result of the query had more than one record. Rewriting it to:

```
var mailTo = db.DRAFT_DLs
    .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == argMailTo)
    .Select(dd => new MailAddress(dd.EMAIL))
    .ToList();

var mailCc = db.DRAFT_DLs
    .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == "ALL")
    .Select(dd => new MailAddress(dd.EMAIL))
    .ToList();

// ...

mailTo.ForEach(rcpt => mail.To.Add(rcpt));
mailCc.ForEach(rcpt => mail.CC.Add(rcpt));
```

solved the issue. Still not known is the reason why error was thrown on a different line tough.

Comment: Show the exception please

Comment: This exception would usually occur on a call to `Single` where the sequence contains more than one item. It's hard to see how it could occur from the code in your question. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Break the linq statement into a set of distinct statements, calling .ToList() after each statement, then tell us which one the exception is thrown on.

Comment: Stacktrace would be appreciated as well. Unless Something Strange is done in DRAFT_DLs, I don't see either why it fails.

Comment: Your stack trace has a `SingleOrDefault` call in it, where is that coming from? Is there any more code? This is the most likely cause of the exception, as noted above.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, there's `SingleOrDefault` in next line but why would the exception be thrown on a line before?

Comment: That's most likely your problem. You are expecting zero or one "ALL" mailing lists. So you have one of two problems: your assumption is correct, there should only be one "ALL", so the problem is elsewhere (likely the data); or your assumption is incorrect so using `SingleOrDefault` is incorrect. There is a similar method called `FirstOrDefault`, but that comes with it's own assumptions on the data.

Comment: @AdrianChrostowski No idea why the exception is coming from line 94, are you compiling with optimisations? That can screw around with line numbering and stack trace details.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth, you're right the 'ALL' distributions has more than one row. I use Visual Studio. So modifing the 95 line to look alike the 94 and 127 alike 126 should fix the issue?

Comment: @AdrianChrostowski: You dont have SingleOrDefault in line 94. Its in line 95. So it make no sense. Are you sure the project is getting built correctly. Are you getting any errors during the build? And problem statement is not clear. On line 95 are you expecting a list or a scalar? you can use FirstOrDefault() if you want to get the first matching element when there are more than 1 in the list.

Comment: @JatinNathPrusty I get no errors during build. I'll post if refactoring the code helps.

Answer (score 3):

It's not thrown on the first but on the second line:

```
string mailCc = db.DRAFT_DLs
   .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == "ALL")
   .Select(dd => dd.EMAIL)
   .SingleOrDefault() ?? "";
```

If you use [`Enumerable.SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault(v=vs.100).aspx)(or `Single`) you say that zero or one records are ok but more than one is exceptional. That's why you get the exception. With `Single` zero is also exceptional. Maybe you want to use [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
string mailCc = db.DRAFT_DLs
   .Where(dd => dd.MX_DL == "ALL")
   .Select(dd => dd.EMAIL)
   .FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`SingleOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451(v=vs.100).aspx) tells us that:

> InvalidOperationException *(is thrown when)* The input sequence contains more than one element.

In your case, this means that in `db.DRAFT_DLs` you have more than one record where `dd.MX_DL` equals `"ALL"`.

You should be able to verify this by querying the `DRAFT_DL` table in your database.